# How take date in class constructor?

Tags: typescript, angular

have json

```
{"id":1,"name":"123","dateoff":"2016-01-12T13:30:46.358+05:00","available":true}
```

and have class

```
export class Compaing {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string,
                public dateoff: Date, public available:boolean) { }
}
```

But when i use in angular2

```
<Compaing>res.json()
```

It dont work. In compaing.dateoff not date, it's string.
How parse json string date to Date with constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
export class Compaing {
    dateoff:Date;
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string,
                public dateoffstr: string, public available:boolean)        {
       this.dateoff =new Date(dateoffstr);
    }
}
```